# Converting YYWW to date in Oracle

Tags: sql, date, dayofweek, week-number

I'm having some trouble with converting week number to date in oracle 11g.
The thing is that i have two columns *id|week_code* and I'd like to convert it to first day (monday) of this week.
So let's say that i have *1202* which is *2nd week of 2012*, so the result would be like: *09-January-2012*.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this approach: (not tested).

```
with date_wk as (
       select to_date('01/01/'||'20'||substr(%input%,1,2), 'MM/DD/
RRRR') + rownum - 4 dt
        from dual
        connect by level <= 366
),
wk_dt as (
        select dt, to_number(to_char(dt, 'iw')) wk_of_yr

        from date_wk
)
select min(dt)
from wk_dt
where wk_of_yr = substr(%input%,3,2)
```

to get the date you desire, and change it format to 'DD-MONTH-YYYY'.